# Background color of texture not showing properly when taking printscreen (snapshot with javascript)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, textures

I have a mesh (something like a plane) that I color in red and set a map with a texture.

The texture is like two black lines and the rest is transparent. I've set a png with the two black lines and transparent background for the other parts of the image to to get that effect.

When I'm seeing it in the browser it is showing pretty well, as seen here:

[image]

I want to take a snapshot of that. The problem is here, when I try to take the printscreen with javascript, the result is like that:

[image]

The red if lost and only appears near the black lines.

How can I keep the same result with the printscreen?

Thank you

Comment: SO uses markdown for formatting. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: How are you taking the snapshot using JavaScript? That is likely where the problem is. Show some code.

Comment: Thanks @MattBall. 
@KevinReid, I call  a function in a button to get the snapshot `$( "input[type=submit], button" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
  switch (this.id) {
   case "guar":save();return false;
   break;` and then that function is: `function save() {

    window.open( renderer.domElement.toDataURL('image/png'), 'mywindow' );

   }` Thank you